# `String.raw` when last character is `\`

Tags: javascript

`String.raw` is very useful. For example:

```
let path = String.raw`C:\path\to\file.html`
```

However, when the last character of the template string is `\`, it becomes an syntax error.

```
let path = String.raw`C:\path\to\directory\`
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal

Tentatively, I use this method.

```
let path = String.raw`C:\path\to\directory\ `.trimRight()
```

Can I write template string which last character is `\` using `String.raw`?

Comment: \ is used to escape a character

Comment: If you want a solution with slightly less typing you could use ``let path = String.raw`C:\path\to\directory` + '\\'``. (I find that easier to read, too, because a space right before the closing ` isn't necessarily obvious.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few different possible workarounds. My favorite is probably creating a [custom template tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) `dir` to solve the problem for you. I think it makes the syntax cleaner and more semantic.

```js
let path

// Uglier workarounds
path = String.raw `C:\path\to\directory${`\\`}`
path = String.raw `C:\path\to\directory`+`\\`
path = `C:\\path\\to\\directory\\`

// Cleanest solution
const dir = ({raw}) => raw + `\\`

path = dir `C:\path\to\directory`

console.log(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/ escape sequences are left untouched, aside from \$ \{ and \`, in template strings.   Thus one cannot escape the escape character.  Based on this it looks like your solution is the best way to achieve your goal.