# how to create a raw string when it's last character is a `\` in python

Tags: python, string

As we all know,we can create a string like this:

```
str1 = r"\abc\test"
```

But if I want put the `\` in the end of a string like:

```
str2 = r"\abc\test\"
```

A syntax error occurs !
I have found an answer,but it's in `JavaScript`.
[`String.raw` when last character is `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604680/string-raw-when-last-character-is)
So,How to deal this in `python`

Comment: escape the `'\'` with the escape character which is `'\'`. so it will look like this `'\\'`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Then you'll have 2 backslashes at the end of your string.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the updated duplicate helps explain this raw string behaviour.

Comment: Append a throwaway character, then slice it out `r'\dontcare'[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concat another normal string:

```
>>> r'\abc\test' + '\\'
'\\abc\\test\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

duplicated [Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

> Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal, not as a line continuation.